# travis job is failing as "const" is not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, restify

I'm trying to fix my PR in [node restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/pull/1695) npm package. Unfortunately [travis job](https://travis-ci.org/restify/node-restify/jobs/430510936) is failing for node 4 with the following error;

```
./node_modules/.bin/nodeunit test/*.test.js
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/restify/node-restify/node_modules/anumargak/node_modules/randexp/lib/randexp.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/restify/node-restify/node_modules/anumargak/src/util.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
make: *** [test] Error 1
npmERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I've already placed 'use strict', removed const keyword. But it is still failing for the same reason. I've also tried to test locally and it is passing.

How can I fix it?

[Here](https://github.com/node-muneem/anumargak/blob/master/src/util.js) is the code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and fixed the build. It was not because of the file it was reported on but because of postinstall script. I missed it to update as per node 4 compatible changes as it was not the part of actual source code.

I'm still not able to relate the bug with actual problem. But solved it.